# Segmentation fault при считывании из файла

Tags: c, файлы, список, segmentation-fault

Если делаю ввод с клавиатуры (gets), то программа работает без проблем. Но если считываю из файла в массив, то вылетает SegFault 11, хотя массив заполняется.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#define PATH "/Users/ivanrud/Desktop/CLionProjects/untitled"

typedef struct node {
    char *word;
    struct node *next;
} node;

typedef struct list {
    node *head;
    node *last;
    int size;
} list;

int isLetter(char c) {
    if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int wordLen(char *c) {
    int i = 0, count = 0;
    while (isLetter(c[i])) {
        count++;
        i++;
    }
    return count;
}

void pushSort(node *n, list *l) {
    if (l->size == 0) {
        l->head = n;
        l->last = n;
        l->size++;
    }
    else {
        node *cur = l->head;
        node *buf;
        while (1) {
            if (strcmp(n->word, cur->word) == 0) {
                buf = cur->next;
                cur->next = n;
                cur->next->next = buf;
                l->size++;
                break;
            }
            else if (strcmp(n->word, cur->word) > 0 && cur->next != NULL ) {
                if (strcmp(n->word, cur->next->word) < 0) {
                    buf = cur->next;
                    cur->next = n;
                    cur->next->next = buf;
                    l->size++;
                    break;
                }
                cur = cur->next;
                continue;
            }
            else if (strcmp(n->word, cur->word) > 0 && cur->next == NULL) {
                buf = cur->next;
                cur->next = n;
                cur->next->next = buf;
                l->size++;
                break;
            }
            else if (strcmp(n->word, cur->word) < 0 && cur == l->head) {
                buf = l->head;
                l->head = n;
                n->next = buf;
                l->size++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

void pushBack(list *l, char *w) {
    int i = 0;
    node* Node = (node*) malloc (sizeof(node));
    Node->word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*wordLen(w)+1);
    Node->next = NULL;
    while (w[i] != '\0') {
        Node->word[i] = w[i];
        i++;
    }
    Node->word[i] = '\0';
    i = 0;
    if (l->size == 0) {
        l->head = Node;
        l->last = Node;
        l->size++;
    }
    else {
        node *cur = l->last;
        cur->next = Node;
        l->last = Node;
        l->size++;
    }
}

void merge(list *r, list *l1, list *l2) {
    node *cur1 = l1->head;
    node *cur2 = l2->head;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (cur1 != NULL && cur2 != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(cur1->word, cur2->word) <= 0) {
            pushBack(r, cur1->word);
            cur1 = cur1->next;
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        else {
            pushBack(r, cur2->word);
            cur2 = cur2->next;
            j++;
            continue;
        }
    }
    while (cur2 != NULL) {
        while (j < l2->size) {
            pushBack(r, cur2->word);
            cur2 = cur2->next;
            j++;
        }
    }
    while (cur1 != NULL) {
        while (i < l1->size) {
            pushBack(r, cur1->word);
            cur1 = cur1->next;
            i++;
        }
    }
}

void printReverse(node *n) {
    if (n->next == NULL) {
        printf("%s ", n->word);
    }
    else {
        printReverse(n->next);
        printf("%s ", n->word);
    }
}

void printList(list * l) {
    int i = 0;
    node* cur = l->head;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        printf("%s ", cur->word);
        cur = cur->next;
        i++;
    }
}

int main() {
    chdir(PATH);
    char str1[200] = { '\0' }, str2[200] = { '\0' }, str3[200] = { '\0' };
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    FILE *S1, *S2, *S3;
    char *p;

    S1 = fopen("S1.txt", "r");
    while ((str1[i] = fgetc(S1)) != EOF) {
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;

    S2 = fopen("S2.txt", "r");
    while ((str2[i] = fgetc(S2)) != EOF) {
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;

    S3 = fopen("S3.txt", "r");
    while ((str3[i] = fgetc(S3)) != EOF) {
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;

    //LIST1
    node* Node1 = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    list* List1 = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    List1->last = NULL;
    List1->head = NULL;
    List1->size = 0;

    while (1) {
        if (isLetter(str1[i]) && i == 0) {
            p = &str1[i];
            Node1->word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*wordLen(p) + 1);
        }
        if (isLetter(str1[i]) && !isLetter(str1[i - 1]) && i != 0) {
            p =&str1[i];
            Node1->word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*wordLen(p) + 1);
        }
        if (isLetter(str1[i]) == 1) {
            Node1->word[j] = str1[i];
            j++;
        }
        if (isLetter(str1[i]) == 0 && isLetter(str1[i - 1]) == 1) {
            Node1->word[j] = '\0';
            Node1->next = NULL;
            pushSort(Node1, List1);
            j = 0;
            Node1 = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        }
        if (str1[i] == '\0') {
            j=0;
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;

    //LIST2
    node* Node2 = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    list* List2 = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    List2->last = NULL;
    List2->head = NULL;
    List2->size = 0;

    while (1) {
        if (isLetter(str2[i]) && i == 0) {
            p = &str2[i];
            Node2->word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*wordLen(p) + 1);
        }
        if (isLetter(str2[i]) && !isLetter(str2[i - 1]) && i != 0) {
            p =&str2[i];
            Node2->word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*wordLen(p) + 1);
        }
        if (isLetter(str2[i]) == 1) {
            Node2->word[j] = str2[i];
            j++;
        }
        if (isLetter(str2[i]) == 0 && isLetter(str2[i - 1]) == 1) {
            Node2->word[j] = '\0';
            Node2->next = NULL;
            pushSort(Node2, List2);
            j = 0;
            Node2 = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        }
        if (str2[i] == '\0') {
            j=0;
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;

    //LIST3
    node* Node3 = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    list* List3 = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    List3->last = NULL;
    List3->head = NULL;
    List3->size = 0;

    while (1) {
        if (isLetter(str3[i]) && i == 0) {
            p = &str3[i];
            Node3->word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*wordLen(p) + 1);
        }
        if (isLetter(str3[i]) && !isLetter(str3[i - 1]) && i != 0) {
            p =&str3[i];
            Node3->word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*wordLen(p) + 1);
        }
        if (isLetter(str3[i]) == 1) {
            Node3->word[j] = str3[i];
            j++;
        }
        if (isLetter(str3[i]) == 0 && isLetter(str3[i - 1]) == 1) {
            Node3->word[j] = '\0';
            Node3->next = NULL;
            pushSort(Node3, List3);
            j = 0;
            Node3 = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        }
        if (str3[i] == '\0') {
            j=0;
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;

    list* listRes = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    listRes->last = NULL;
    listRes->head = NULL;
    listRes->size = 0;

    list* listResFinal = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    listResFinal->last = NULL;
    listResFinal->head = NULL;
    listResFinal->size = 0;

   //merge
    merge(listRes, List1, List2);
    merge(listResFinal, listRes, List3);
    printList(listResFinal);

    free(Node1); free(List1);
    free(Node2); free(List2);
    free(Node3); free(List3);
    free(listRes); free(listResFinal);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Уточните вопрос. В каком месте происходит ошибка. Какие данные в файле. Из Вашего вопроса следует, что Вы используете `gets`, но в коде я не нашел вызова этой функции.

Comment: Вашу проблему не удаётся воспроизвести. Покажите данные.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev , я скомпилировал данный код на винде и он нормально работает. Но на macOS выдаёт Segmentation fault 11

Answer (score 4):

Как я уже писал в комментариях под вопросом, воспроизвести проблему не удаётся. И, если честно, ревьювить всю пелёнку кода не хочется. Но я могу показать, как искать причины segfault'а самостоятельно с помощью отладчика. Так как ответ получается обобщённый, и вероятно не все его читатели будут использовать CLion, отладчик использую самый популярный - [gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/).

Подопытный код (взят из реального вопроса):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *buf;

    fgets(buf, 1024, stdin);
    printf("%s\n", buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Компилируем его с отладочной информацией:

```
$ gcc -g -o dummy example.c
```

Пробуем запустить и закономерно получаем ошибку сегментирования после ввода произвольной строки. Открываем подопытного в отладчике:

```
$ gdb dummy

GNU gdb (Debian 7.12-6) 7.12.0.20161007-git
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from dummy...done.
(gdb)
```

Запускам программу командой отладчика `run` и вводим строку

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/thedeadone/playground/c/dummy
abcd

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__GI__IO_getline_info (fp=fp@entry=0x7ffff7dd38c0 <_IO_2_1_stdin_>,
    buf=buf@entry=0x0, n=1022, delim=delim@entry=10,
    extract_delim=extract_delim@entry=1, eof=eof@entry=0x0) at iogetline.c:77
77      iogetline.c: Нет такого файла или каталога.
```

В этом месте иногда даже бывает внятная ошибка, помогающая понять причину падения без дальнейших телодвижений. Но, как видно, не всегда. Из выданной нам ошибки ясно только то, что программа получила от операционной системы сигнал `SIGSEGV` означающий, что произошло обращение к недоступной программе области памяти.

Вводим команду `backtrace` для просмотра стека вызовов. В такой примитивной программе, как наш пример, можно обойтись и без этого, но в более серьёзных - это важный этап анализа проблемы:

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  __GI__IO_getline_info (fp=fp@entry=0x7ffff7dd38c0 <_IO_2_1_stdin_>,
    buf=buf@entry=0x0, n=1022, delim=delim@entry=10,
    extract_delim=extract_delim@entry=1, eof=eof@entry=0x0) at iogetline.c:77
#1  0x00007ffff7aa2658 in __GI__IO_getline (
    fp=fp@entry=0x7ffff7dd38c0 <_IO_2_1_stdin_>, buf=buf@entry=0x0,
    n=<optimized out>, delim=delim@entry=10,
    extract_delim=extract_delim@entry=1) at iogetline.c:34
#2  0x00007ffff7aa13eb in _IO_fgets (buf=0x0, n=<optimized out>,
    fp=0x7ffff7dd38c0 <_IO_2_1_stdin_>) at iofgets.c:53
#3  0x0000555555554757 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe598) at example.c:8
```

В подавляющем большинстве случаев проблема не в системных или библиотечных вызовах, поэтому стоит обратить внимание на вызовы в своём коде. В нашем случае - это только третий кадр стека. На него и переключимся:

```
(gdb) frame 3
#3  0x0000555555554757 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe598) at example.c:8
8           fgets(buf, 1024, stdin);
```

И сразу увидим строчку, в которой произошло падение. Проверяем куда указывает `buf`

```
(gdb) print buf
$1 = 0x0
```

Указатель `buf` содержит `NULL`. Автор программы не выделил память. Завершаем работу программы и отладчика вводом соответствующих команд

```
(gdb) kill
Kill the program being debugged? (y or n) y
(gdb) quit
```

Отладчик - полезнейший инструмент программиста, а gdb - прекрасный его представитель, который обязательно стоит освоить.